# How to set TrackableName for an ImageTarget at runtime in Vuforia SDK for Unity 3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using Vuforia's SDK for Unity 3D platform. I am trying to set the TrackableName dynamically at runtime. I found a code

```
GameObject prefab = Instantiate(imageTarget) as GameObject;
ImageTargetBehaviour imgTargetBeh = prefab.GetComponent();
imgTargetBeh.DataSetPath = "QCAR/Test.xml";
imgTargetBeh.TrackableName = "Daddy";
imgTargetBeh.mInitializedInEditor = true;
myModel.transform.parent = prefab.transform;
```

The problem is I am getting error with DataSetPath, TrackableName, mInitializedInEditor.
The ImageTargetBehaviour class does not have above mentioned properties.
So how/where to set the properties?

Thanks,
Sris

Answer (score 0):

I can't yet global comment, so I'll ask here for more info and update this when I have it.

The second line worries me, because you're not telling Unity what kind of component to get. Try `GetComponent(typeof(ImageTargetBehaviour))` instead of the null parameters.

> The problem is I am getting error with DataSetPath, TrackableName, mInitializedInEditor. The ImageTargetBehaviour class does not have above mentioned properties. So how/where to set the properties?

If the ImageTargetBehaviour class doesn't have these properties, then why are you trying to access them? Does the documentation instruct you to do so? If so, then something is wrong with your ImageTargetBehaviour.js script.